# Lighttpd + Multiple Users + SSH

Tags: permissions, centos, lighttpd

Is it possible to have multiple SSH users who can't read/write each others files but still allowing Lighttpd to serve their files?

Each user would have different domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make each user's files readable by their usergroup, and then add lighttpd to each user's usergroup.

If we have `bob` and `charlie`, and lighttpd is running as `www-data`:

```
# Bob and Charlie own their public_html folders
# And cannot see each others' files
chown bob:bob /home/bob/public_html
chmod 770 /home/bob/public_html

chown charlie:charlie /home/charlie/public_html
chmod 770 /home/charlie/public_html

# But the webserver can see both their files
adduser www-data bob
adduser www-data charlie
```

This will add the `www-data` user to the primary groups for `bob` and `charlie`, and allow the webserver to read any files marked under their group with group access. (Assuming that your webserver is running as `www-data`. This might vary from system to system)

Comment: Darth, could you expand a bit with an example command?

Comment: I know it wasn't part of the original question... but what about PHP?  PHP will be able to have access to everything so it seems trivial to use PHP as a proxy to read / write.

Comment: @Michael PHP will have access based on whatever user PHP is running under. If you're running php as an internal wbeserver module (like with apache), then it has whatever access that the webserver does. If you have it running externally (like with `php-fpm`), then that usually runs under another user, which *also* needs to be granted access to each user's files.

Comment: @Luke Uh.... those are *all* example commands. Can you be more specific with what  you're asking?

Comment: @DarthAndroid Sorry, when I saw that, it didn't have any commands (it was in the LQ queue)

Comment: @Luke Actually, looking at timestamps, I think I may have added those in response to your comment, but for some reason [SU] had it flagged as a new comment. I'm still confused what happened there.

Comment: Oh well... Either way, you got the upvote from me that you deserve